# Content lost when window is repainted

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-2010, paint, gdi

I am currently messing around with the windows API in C. I thought it would be funny to make a simple chalkboard. Everything is working fine. It's drawing etc, etc.
The problem is that the contents are lost when the window is repainted/updated/resized...
I thought maybe I should save the HDC or something, but then I don't know how to put it back.
How do I solve this? I figured it shouldn't be a very difficult question to answer, yet I can't really find anything on google somehow.

Answer (score 3):

You need to handle the `WM_PAINT` event and repaint the invalidated region in its entirety. That's what `WM_PAINT` is -- a request from the system to redraw a dirty region.

For your specific application it sounds like you should create an off-screen device context (`CreateCompatibleDC`), a corresponding bitmap (`CreateBitmap`) of the size of your canvas, do all the drawing operations there and call `InvalidateRect` on your window. When `WM_PAINT` fires call `BitBlt` to transfer the relevant portion of that bitmap to the screen.